# Using Craft environment variable for Asset source subfolder

Tags: s3, environmentvariables

[image: Subfolder Environment Variable]
[image: S3 subfolder]

I have an environment variable "bucketUrl" that I would like to use as the subfolder path in my S3 bucket. However, Craft is not parsing the variable. When I upload an image, I see in my S3 bucket that a new subfolder "{bucketUrl}" was created with the uploaded image inside it. Why is Craft not parsing the environment variable? Craft is parsing my site url variable I am using elsewhere in the Craft admin, so I'm not sure why Craft is not parsing the bucket url variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#setting-support), environment variables are currently only parsed in 3 places in the control panel.

- File System Path (in asset source settings)
- URL (in asset source settings)
- Site URL (in Settings → General)

So they won't work in the "subfolder" setting.  You can add a [feature request](https://feedback.craftcms.com) if you think that should change.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but on Craft 3 - folder name is called {baseAssetsPath} instead of getting parsed. I have the same setup but using Craft 2 site and that is working fine.

Comment: Even if I use the full reference folders still get created like {craft.app.config.general.environmentVariables.baseAssetsPath}

Comment: @SeanDelaney `environmentalVariables` have gone away with Craft 3; instead you can put multi-environment things like this into your `volumes.php` config file. There's an example of that here: [Craft3-Multi-Environment](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft3-multi-environment#asset-volumes)